# How can I modify the 'oauth/token' controller of Gitlab source code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Recently, I build a self-managed Gitlab instance via [gitlab-development-kit](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-development-kit/).

I used the database migration to added a `payload`(string) column to the `Users` table. And I want to add the 'payload' to the response of requests to '/oauth/token'.

I did a full text search for the string '/oauth/token' in Gitlab's source code and it seems like there are only two ruby file including the string:

[image]

You can find these two file here: [application.rb](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/master/config/application.rb#L350) and [routes.rb](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/master/config/routes.rb#L53)

I'm new to ruby and ruby on rails. I'm confused about the `via: :options` since in the [ruby on rails documents](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), the value of the `via` always be `all` or `post/get`

My point is if the `via` here is `options`, how does the `/oauth/token` api receive a POST or GET request?

Comment: I note that the [`Oauth::TokensController`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/master/app/controllers/oauth/tokens_controller.rb#L3) is extended from [`Doorkeeper::TokensController`](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/main/app/controllers/doorkeeper/tokens_controller.rb) which implements the `create` function. So, maybe I should overwrite the `create` function in the `Oauth::TokensController`.